# Mixed results with is_page() WordPress function, when using either $this, or self

Tags: php, wordpress, this, self

I'm trying to understand something. I inherited an old Wordpress plugin, and I'm chewing my way through converting it from PHP5 -> PHP8.

I came across this check, which caused an error when executing:

> Notice: Accessing static property PropertySearch::$listing_details_template_name as non static

I found online that this can be fixed, by using `self` instead of `$this` to access a static member. However, when I pass the `self` version to the `is_page` Wordpress function, it returns `false`, where-as when I pas the `$this` version, it returns `true`.

When I view the value of both `self::$listing_details_template_name` and `$this->listing_details_template_name` they contain the exact same string.

One thing I've noticed through debugging, is that upon entering the `is_page` function, the `$page` variable is NULL when using `$this->listing_details_template_name`, and contains the template name when using `self::$listing_details_template_name`, and since `$page` is NOT NULL, this passes the function, and returns `false`.

[Here's a quick demo of what I'm talking about.](https://imgur.com/lvHOWzA)

Ultimately, I'm trying to find out why this is happening, and what I can do to circumvent the original error, and or this new issue I'm faced with.

is_page(): https://wp-kama.com/function/is_page

```
global $wp_query;

    if (is_page(self::$listing_details_template_name)) {
        echo nl2br ("[DEBUG] - self2 = " . self::$listing_details_template_name . " \r\n");
    }

    if (is_page($this->listing_details_template_name)) {
        echo nl2br ("[DEBUG] - this2 = " . self::$listing_details_template_name . " \r\n");
    }
```

[EDIT] - For the time being, I've added this to the `query.php` file of WordPress.

```
    if ($page = 'property-search-single-property-details-template.php') {
        $page = NULL;
    }
```

However, this is just a bandaid so I can continue debugging. I would love a solution that does NOT involve me modifying the core WordPress files. Or at the very least, some further understanding of why this is happening.